# How to read image field from MSSQL with PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, image

I am creating a web site that needs to synchronise an online MySQL database reading from the offline MSSQL server. All communication and reading all fields from MSSQL is working OK except that image field. I have been working with PHP and Mysql for some time and know how to insert/retrieve images to/from a MySQL database(using BLOBS). I have tried the same concept first with MSSQL and I just can't get it to work. Does anyone have any experience working with inserting/retrieving images from MSSQL using php? It has been busting my balls for a few days already.. Here are the code combinations that I have tried and didn't work..

```
<
?php

$conn = mssql_connect("COMP1");
mssql_select_db("datalab",$conn);


// storing a file
$datastring = file_get_contents("banner.jpg");
$data = unpack("H*hex", $datastring);
mssql_query("insert into milos (id,naziv, slika)
values ('2','img2.jpg', 0x".$data['hex'].")");

// retrieving


$result = mssql_query("select slika from milos where naziv = 'img2.jpg'");
$row = mssql_fetch_array($result);
header("Content-type: image/jpeg;");

$data = $row['slika'];



echo $data;


//echo $slika;


?>
```

---

```
<
?php


$conn = mssql_connect("COMP1");
mssql_select_db("datalab",$conn);


$result = mssql_query("select slika from milos where naziv = 'img.jpg'");
$row = mssql_fetch_array($result);
header("Content-type: image/jpeg;");

$data = $row['slika'];

$datas = substr($data,78);


echo $datas;




?>
```

---

```
<
?php

$conn = mssql_connect("COMP1");
mssql_select_db("datalab",$conn);



$result = mssql_query("select slika from milos where naziv = 'img.jpg'");
$row = mssql_fetch_array($result);
header("Content-type: image/bmp;");

$data = $row['slika'];
$data_pos = strpos($data,"JFIF");
$datas = substr($data,$data_pos - 6);

echo $datas;



?>
```

Can any one help me?

Thanks in advance..
Nimmy....

Answer (score 1):

Search **php.ini** and find the lines

```
;mssql.textlimit = 4096
```

and

```
;mssql.textsize = 4096
```

Replace the value to `2147483647` like this:

```
mssql.textlimit = 2147483647
mssql.textsize = 2147483647
```

Also you can do the following just after making a connection.

```
mssql_query("SET TEXTSIZE 2147483647");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to upload SQL Server 2005 Driver for PHP. Please find more information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc793139%28v=sql.90%29.aspx).