# SQL Server varbinary, display the image in PHP

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I have a SQL server database that has a varbinary(max) column that contains data for a bitmap image.
I need to display this data as an image on a PHP page.

Any idea how I would go about this? I havn't found alot of information on the internet as to how to do it.

When I look at the data through the management studio, it looks like `0x42DBE3400000...,`
whereas if I retrieve it thorugh ODBC and echo it to the screen, it looks like `Qk2+NAAAAAAAAD4AAAAoAAAArgEAAPAAAAAB`.

I havn't worked very much with binary data before so I'm not sure what to do from here!
Any help appreciated

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read image field from MSSQL with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3474456/how-to-read-image-field-from-mssql-with-php)

Comment: I did see that but it provides no solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the page to not look like garbled text, you will need to output a `Content-Type` header in order for the browser to recognize that the page is an image and not a text/html page.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: image/x-bmp');

echo '{display the image's binary content here}';
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've used the following code, but I still get just characters: <?php
include("../../../cfg.inc");
require_once($dir["base"]["inc"] . "supplymaster.inc");
$status = get_pod("R1","PAG","123");
if ( $status !== NULL ) {
  header("Content-type: image/x-bmp");
  echo $status;
exit;
}
?>

Comment: Do any of the included files output any information? Such as HTML or even other headers? If the system you're testing on is open to the public, you can try using [this HTTP header viewer](http://www.rexswain.com/httpview.html) and see if the `Content-Type` header is not getting through.

Comment: Hi. No none of the include files do. I created a string with just the data from the query itself and got the same result. The page is on the web, but behind a private area. Does firebug show me this information?

Comment: I've just gone to the page again and it showed up a download window, so im sure the content-type is working. When I opened with windows picture viewer, it couldnt open it. When viewing the data in SQL server, is that in HEX format I'm guessing? I saved the data from there into a variable, and used hextobin before echoing, but still no cigar :(

Comment: Do you use output buffering (ob_start, ob_start('ob_gzhandler'), etc)? How are you saving the image to the database? Are you sure it is binary safe?

Comment: The image is in a legacy system- I actually have no idea how the image is inserted, but it is displayable in their application (which is a very very old language, i believe fortran). I've found the hex of another image and it will work, so there must be something funky going on with the image itself. I might get in contact with the company and see if they can shed some light

Comment: No, it will display it through PHP when I use the Hex of a known working image (e.g. pull up paint and create a bmp), but the images coming from the DB do not seem to work.

Comment: Oh, I see. Have you tried saving $status to a file, like `file_put_contents('test.bmp', $status);` and opening it up to see if that works? Maybe there is something wrong with the get_pod function.

Comment: Finally got there! It was the ODBC driver! It was limiting the string length to 8194 characters. I just added odbc_longreadlen($result, 131072); to the odbc call and it works now. Thankyou for all your help. I am marking this as answered as there were 2 problems here, and the above did help me display it