# display image from database in php displays partialy

Tags: php

I am having trouble displaying images from a MS SQL database. I know it's not the best way but that the source I got. So basicly my problem is i can't show the whole image. I am troubleshooting and failing. When I look in the database the binary data in the BLOB are like this (heidsql):

0x89504E470D0A1A0A0000000D4948445200000258000004B0080600000027A134...

but when SELECT the data and output it with no encoding i get this:

```
    �PNG  IHDRX�'�4 sRGB���gAMA���atEXtSoftwareAdobe ImageReadyq�e<���IDATx^�}�Ǒ��V,-�X+i�d1�bfY�f��d�(33C��afft8q�p�\����]R}
���5����>���sW}U�3�iw���H�"E�)R��@D�)R�H�"E��G�LQ|
�U�nݺ   �w���=zdJR��dz��)~�n�X�%}����|
�*Ʊ�s1.e�a\Ǹ�q1��G3�0aLg�a�`�2�0�#=�c��\���c�m�|
�΃�ܟpO¡��   
��)E�%So�C��'Ĕ���fLd�g����#o��3��{����ʪ�:t�� 
>�ƍG���4|�pZ�n͝;��̞M3fL�ذ���wذa�>h��?�����w�^��s}
����9��3��]�ՌٌQ�*F�Κ��x�O��x�}��o�yR���=��)����!
��ݳ�����ɸ��iK�9s&m޲�N9�d:���������s5}�3��O}���/
�^~�e��~� }�+_�.�@�?������}��_g�+��/~Q����g>�i��)��?
H�|�;���=O�<��|�M\�|ڽ{7m߾��-[J�f���ȑ#�4`����~�� 
��ƭ���f���e�cf@�Gz�G��� ���0|
��;O*�R�Q2E��:0ݷ�q��'N��;��ݲ�>����W��U����G�e��eF����
```

When I try to display the image it only displays 1/4 of the image.

This is my code:

```
$server = "some-server"
$link = mssql_connect($server,'user','password')

if (!$link || !mssql_select_db('database_name', $link)) {
    die('Unable to connect or select database!');
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM tabel_name WHERE id='1'"
$version = mssql_query($query,$link);
$row = mssql_fetch_row($version);

$data = $row[1];
$data64 = base64_encode($data);
echo "<img height='1200' src='data:image/png;base64, ".$data64 ."'/>"
```

I should add that the same data is being used and it works on a .ASP page and displays the images whole while my solution only displays 1/4 of the image. Content is set as `IMAGE` in the database.

Comment: Did you verified the byte size of image you stored and what you retrieved from db are same ?

Comment: No. The database is not mine and was used before me so i can't realy verify byte size but as mentioned the same data works in already set .asp page, with the same image data and it displays the image whole.

Is there a limit of how much data can be transferred over the query ? It looks to me like some data is missing since the image is 1200 x 600 px big.

Comment: I missed asp part. also I hope this is not the problem. src='data:imaeg

Comment: no the imaeg is not the issue :) just a typo here. Will edit it.

Comment: what does the strlen(bin2hex($data)) says ?

Comment: Not sure but may be this helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3474456/how-to-read-image-field-from-mssql-with-php

Comment: The link you provided worked :) finnaly. Was looking here on stackoverflow and google and could not find an anwser. Thank you kind sir. Maybe add and anwser and i will mark it as the anwser. So there was a limit i got from the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few check list for your problem.

- Make sure have the file completely in db.
  strlen() in php side & DATALENGTH() in db.
- Make sure you fetch the result properly.
  some times it can be php ini issue. 
  https://stackoverflow.com/a/14419487/8197560

0x89504E4 ... is the hex representation of the binary image, which look correct.

Comment: Thank you. So the problem was the amount of data php was getting and was limited. The fix was using mssql_query("SET TEXTSIZE 2147483647");